# How to get video thumbnail from video id in sdcard smoothly ?

Tags: android, caching, video, bitmap, video-thumbnails

I want to get video thumbnail from video id which is stored in sdcard , smoothly. Actually i already get the thumbnail by using bitmap but it slightly hangup the main thread while getting thumbnail. I want the procedure where i can get the image and save it firstly in cache memory so that my main thread will not hangup and finally it will show smoothly..........
Here is the bitmap procedure

ContentResolver crThumb = _context.getContentResolver();

Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail( crThumb, _videoList.get(position).getID(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(curThumb);

Answer (score 0):

Getting thumbnail directly from video will take time ,so in order to take thumbnail you can use asynctask to read thumbnail, once you got the thumbnail you can set it to your imageview ,`public class ThumbnailFetcher extends AsyncTask{

```
String mVideoPath;
ThumbnailManagerCallback mCallback;

public interface ThumbnailManagerCallback {
    public void onThumbnailReceived(Bitmap thumnail, String path);
}

public ThumbnailFetcher(ThumbnailManagerCallback callback){
    mCallback = callback;
}
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... param) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mVideoPath = param[0];
    try{

    return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(param[0],
            Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap thumbnail) {
    if(thumbnail != null)
    mCallback.onThumbnailReceived(thumbnail, mVideoPath);
}`
```

the callback can be your adapter .